# MVC3 HttpContext unit testing / mocking options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, httpcontext

So this really applies to several different classes like HttpContext, ConfigurationManager, etc. There are several different ways to handle this, and I have always used wrapper classes to handle this stuff, but I wanted to see what the most common community practice is...

1. Wrapper classes - e.g. I would have an HttpContextService which I pass in via constructor that exposes all the same functionality via flat method calls.
2. Wrapper classes (part 2) - e.g. I would have SPECIFIC service classes, like MembershipService, which LEVERAGES HttpContext behind the scenes. Functions the same as 1, but the naming scheme / usage pattern is a little different as you are exposing specific functions through specific services instead of one monolithic wrapper. The downside is that the number of service classes that need to be injected goes up, but you get some modularity for when you don't need all the features of the monolithic wrapper.
3. ActionFilters and parameters - Use an ActionFilter to automatically pass in certain values needed on a per function basis. MVC only, and limits you to the controller methods, whereas 1 and 2 could be used generically throughout the project, or even in conjunction with this option.
4. Directly mocking HttpContextBase and setting ControllerContext - There are several mocking framework extension methods out there to help with this, but essentially requires you to directly set things as needed. Doesn't require abstractions, which is nice, and can be reused across non-controller tests as well. Still leaves open the question for ConfigurationManager and other static method calls though, so you could end up with injecting that ANYWAY, but leaving HttpContext to be accessed in this other way.

Right now I am kind of doing number 1, so I have an HttpContextService and a ConfigurationManagerService, etc. which I then inject, though I'm leaning toward 2 in the future. 3 seems to be a little too messy for my tastes, but I can see the appeal for controller methods, and the need for a completely separate solution for other areas of code that also use these static classes makes that one kind of poor for me... 4 is still interesting to me as it seems the most "natural" in terms of basic functionality and leverages the built-in methodologies of MVC.

So what is the prevailing Best Practice here? What are people seeing and using in the wild?

Answer (score 0):

There are already "wrapper" classes for HttpContext, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, etc. The MVC framework uses these and you can supply mocks of them to the Controller via the controller context.  You don't need to mock the controller context as you can simply create one with the appropriate values.  The only thing I've found difficult to mock are the helpers, UrlHelper and HtmlHelper. Those have some relatively deep dependencies.  You can fake them in a somewhat reasonable way, UrlHelper shown below.

```
 var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
 var routeData = new RoutedData();

 var controller = new HomeController();
 controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext( httpContext, routeData, controller );
 controller.Url = UrlHelperFactory.CreateUrlHelper( httpContext, routeDate );
```

where

```
 public static class UrlHelperFactory
 {
    public static UrlHelper CreateUrlHelper( HttpContextBase httpContext, RouteData routeData )
    {
        return CreateUrlHelper( httpContext, routeData, "/" );
    }

    public static UrlHelper CreateUrlHelper( HttpContextBase httpContext, RouteData routeData, string url )
    {
        string urlString = string.Format( "http://localhost/{0}/{1}/{2}", routeData.Values["controller"], routeData.Values["action"], routeData.Values["id"] ).TrimEnd( '/' );

        var uri = new Uri( urlString );

        if (httpContext.Request == null)
        {
            httpContext.Stub( c => c.Request ).Return( MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpRequestBase>() ).Repeat.Any();
        }

        httpContext.Request.Stub( r => r.Url ).Return( uri ).Repeat.Any();
        httpContext.Request.Stub( r => r.ApplicationPath ).Return( "/" ).Repeat.Any();

        if (httpContext.Response == null)
        {
            httpContext.Stub( c => c.Response ).Return( MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpResponseBase>() ).Repeat.Any();
        }
        if (url != "/")
        {
            url = url.TrimEnd( '/' );
        }

        httpContext.Response.Stub( r => r.ApplyAppPathModifier( Arg<string>.Is.Anything ) ).Return( url ).Repeat.Any();

        return new UrlHelper( CreateRequestContext( httpContext, routeData ), GetRoutes() );
    }

    public static RequestContext CreateRequestContext( HttpContextBase httpContext, RouteData routeData )
    {
        return new RequestContext( httpContext, routeData );
    }

    // repeat your route definitions here!!!
    public static RouteCollection GetRoutes()
    {
        RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
        routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" );


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

        return routes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, which would be option 4, and this ONLY works for HttpContextBase. I can abstract out this test setup code, as you show, but this doesn't cover OTHER static classes like ConfigurationManager, etc. so you end up with two solutions to the same problem, whereas option 1 or 2 unifies them. As I said they are two different solutions, and I am assuming that you prefer going with option 4 here...

Comment: Except that you're not providing a mock controller context, but an actual controller context with the relevant mocks embedded.  I do use constructor injection for things like FormsAuthentication, MembershipProvider, etc. with appropriate wrappers, though I use these only on my AccountController.  For other stuff I mock the through the HttpContext, like Request, Response, User, Session, etc.

Comment: Doh! My bad, mistake in the original post. That's what I MEANT to say. Fixed now. Any comment on why you like this method instead of encapsulating the object as a whole (option 1) or in part by role (option 2), or did I pretty much hit it with "number of dependencies being injected growing quickly"?